# Inserir dados na tabela através da Array() PHP

Tags: php

Tenho o seguinte PHP:

```
# Prospect
$sql_prospect = "SELECT * FROM interessados LIMIT 100";
$exe_prospect = mysqli_query($link, $sql_prospect);

$i = 0;
while($res_prospect=mysqli_fetch_array($exe_prospect, MYSQLI_ASSOC)){
    $prospect[$i]['uni_id'] = $res_prospect['int_cod_unidade'];
    $prospect[$i]['cur_id'] = $res_prospect['int_cod_curso'];
    $prospect[$i]['usu_id'] = $res_prospect['int_cod_consultora'];
    $prospect[$i]['cam_id'] = $res_prospect['int_cod_campanha'];
    $prospect[$i]['pro_id_origem'] = $res_prospect['int_cod_origem'];
    $prospect[$i]['pro_nome'] = $res_prospect['int_nome'];
    $prospect[$i]['pro_telefone'] = $res_prospect['int_telefone'];
    $prospect[$i]['pro_whatsapp'] = $res_prospect['int_whatsapp'];
    $prospect[$i]['pro_endereco_cep'] = $res_prospect['int_endereco_cep'];
    $prospect[$i]['pro_endereco'] = $res_prospect['int_endereco'];
    $prospect[$i]['pro_endereco_estado'] = $res_prospect['int_endereco_estado'];
    $prospect[$i]['pro_endereco_cidade'] = $res_prospect['int_endereco_cidade'];
    $prospect[$i]['pro_email'] = $res_prospect['int_email'];
    $prospect[$i]['pro_data'] = $res_prospect['int_data'];
    $prospect[$i]['pro_data_nascimento'] = $res_prospect['int_data_nascimento'];
    $prospect[$i]['pro_observacao'] = $res_prospect['int_observacao'];
    $prospect[$i]['pro_status'] = $res_prospect['int_status'];
    $i++;
}
```

De tal forma que, `$prospect,` é atribuída todas as arrays, conforme repasso acima.

Qual seria a forma correta de inserir no banco de dados? Sem eu ter que fazer `"insert into tabela (campo1, campo2, campo3) values (campo1, campo2, campo3).."`

Gostaria de fazer algo dessa forma: `INSERT INTO tabela (todos_os_campos) VALUE (todos_os_campos)`, talvez com algum tipo de implode?

Comment: Com a função `array_keys` você consegue pegar a lista de índices e com a `array_values` os valores. Basta converter ambos para *string* com o `join` (ou `implode`) e montar a SQL.

Comment: É uma solução @AndersonCarlosWoss, mas o meu retorno ficaria dessa forma: INSERT INTO prospect (uni_id,cur_id,usu_id,cam_id,pro_id_origem,pro_nome,pro_telefone,pro_whatsapp,pro_endereco_cep,pro_endereco,pro_endereco_estado,pro_endereco_cidade,pro_email,pro_data,pro_data_nascimento,pro_observacao,pro_status) VALUES (1,24,0,2,63,Leonardo,,(32) 9912-15056,,,0,0,,2016-09-02 20:13:29,0000-00-00,,51), o que daria erro ao inserir.

Comment: Bota tudo com as aspas então. O que for numero o banco resolve.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Oi, 
Pode utilizar este método, utilizo em um script meu.
Adicione as aspas na atribuição e já gere o implode no loop. Aqui tem um [link](https://repl.it/repls/SardonicClearMangabey) do código funcionando

```
$i = 0;
while($i<10){

    $prospect[$i]['uni_id'] = "'abc'";
    $prospect[$i]['cur_id'] = "'abc'";
    $prospect[$i]['usu_id'] = "'ba'";
    $prospect[$i]['cam_id'] = "'abc'";
    $prospect[$i]['pro_id_origem'] = "'abc'";
    $prospect[$i]['pro_nome'] = "'abc'";
    $prospect[$i]['pro_telefone'] = "'abc'";
    $prospect[$i]['pro_whatsapp'] = "'abc'";
    $prospect[$i]['pro_endereco_cep'] = "'abc'";
    $prospect[$i]['pro_endereco'] = "'abc'";
    $prospect[$i]['pro_endereco_estado'] = "'abc'";
    $prospect[$i]['pro_endereco_cidade'] = "'abc'";
    $prospect[$i]['pro_email'] = "'abc'";
    $prospect[$i]['pro_data'] = "'abc'";
    $prospect[$i]['pro_data_nascimento'] = "'abc'";
    $prospect[$i]['pro_observacao'] = "'abc'";
    $prospect[$i]['pro_status'] = "'abc'";
    // verifica se $nomeCampos já não está setado
    if(!isset($nomeCampos)){
        // define nomes colunas
        $nomeCampos = array_keys($prospect[0]);
    }

    $prospect[$i] = '(' . implode(', ', $prospect[$i]) . ')' ;
    $i++;
}
$prospects = implode(', ', $prospect);


$nomeCampos = implode(', ', $nomeCampos);



$sql = "INSERT INTO {$nomeCampos} VALUES ($prospects);";
echo $sql . PHP_EOL;
```